# interacting with UIViews stored inside a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, nsmutablearray, nsobject

a big noob needs help understanding things.

I have three UIViews stored inside a NSMutableArray

```
lanes = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3] retain];

- (void)registerLane:(Lane*)lane {  
    NSLog (@"registering lane:%i",lane);
    [lanes addObject:lane];
}
```

in the NSLog I see: registering lane:89183264

The value displayed in the NSLog (89183264) is what I am after.
I'd like to be able to save that number in a variable to be able to reuse it elsewhere in the code.

The closest I could come up with was this:

```
NSString *lane0 = [lanes objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *description0 = [lane0 description];
NSLog (@"description0:%@",description0);
```

The problem is that description0 gets the whole UIView object, not just the single number (dec 89183264 is hex 0x550d420)

description0's content:

```
description0:<Lane: 0x550d420; frame = (127 0; 66 460); alpha = 0.5; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 2; layer = <CALayer: 0x550d350>>
```

what I don't get is why I get the correct decimal value with with NSLog so easily, but seem to be unable to get it out of the NSMutableArray any other way. I am sure I am missing some "basic knowledge" here, and I would appreciate if someone could take the time and explain what's going on here so I can finally move on. it's been a long day studying.

why can't I save the 89183264 number easily with something like:

```
NSInteger * mylane = lane.id;
or  
NSInteger * mylane = lane;
```

thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really confused as to why you want to save the memory location of the view? Because that's what your '89183264' number is. It's the location of the pointer. When you are calling:

```
NSLog (@"registering lane:%i",lane);
```

...do you get what's actually being printed out there? What the number that's being printed means?

It seems like a really bad idea, especially when if you're subclassing UIView you've already got a lovely .tag property which you can assign an int of your choosing.

You're making life infinitely more complex than it needs to be. Just use a pointer. Say I have an array containing lots of UIViews:

```
UIView *viewToCompare = [myArray objectAtIndex:3];
for (id object in myArray) {
    if (object == viewToCompare) {
        NSLog(@"Found it!");
    }
}
```

That does what you're trying to do - it compares two pointers - and doesn't need any faffing around with ints, etc.

Comment: I am trying to identify the UIView somehow and then later in the code compare if it's the same one. When I do NSLog (@"registering lane:%i",lane); I get 89183264 in the NSLog output. To me it's a unique number that tells me which UIView it is. I have also have .tag assigned. How would I go about saving the .tag value in a variable then ? Is it any easier than the memory location value ?